# How do I use integer operations in Expressions?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to extract some data from text and have following "Expression" which I'm trying to use inside `Compose` action. It tells me that Experssion is not valid. This centers around use of arithmetic substruction in last parameter for `substring`. I can not figure out what is wrong syntax

`substring(body('HTTP'), indexOf(body('HTTP'),'{url:"'), (indexOf(body('HTTP'),'.json"') - indexOf(body('HTTP'),'{url:"')))`

Answer (score 0):

One need to use `sub` Math function instead of `-` sign